# Only be able to press space once every half a sec

Tags: javascript, onkeydown, function-call

When i press spacebar, the function shoot executes.

```
window.onkeydown=function(e){
    var which = e.keyCode;
    if(which == 32){
        shoot();
    }
}
```

If you hold space down, shoot calls many times in a row. I only want the function to execute once every 500ms.

Comment: Use a DateTime variable, store the last pressing time and check the difference with current time

Comment: Maybe keep track of the last time you called `shoot();` and compare that to the current time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function($){

    var lazerCharging = false,
        lazerChargeTime = 500;  // Charge time in ms

    function handleKeyPress(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            shoot(lazerChargeTime);   
        }
    }

    function shoot(chargeTime){

        if(!lazerCharging){        

            lazerCharging = true;       
            $("body").append("pew<br/>");

            setTimeout(function(){
                lazerCharging = false;
            }, chargeTime)            
        }        
    }

    $(window).on("keydown", handleKeyPress);

})($);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYgRH/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to "debounce"

> Using jQuery throttle / debounce, you can pass a delay and function to
>   $.debounce to get a new function, that when called repetitively,
>   executes the original function just once per "bunch" of calls.
>
> This can be especially useful for rate limiting execution of handlers
>   on events that will trigger AJAX requests. Just take a look at this
>   example to see for yourself!

Ben Alman did the hard work for you here: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/

Comment: That seams a lite bit too heavy, isnt there a easier way? more lika a ordinary game there you shoot some flying pigs or whatever

Comment: Sure, there are, see the other answers, megawac's looks pretty solid

Answer (score 1):

Essentially a debounce as MattC suggested. Store the time the function was called last and make sure 500 ms has passed. Also you probably should be using `.addEventListener` instead of `window.onkeydown`

```
(function() {
    var lastCallTime = 0;
    window.onkeydown = function(e){
        var now = Date.now();
        if(e.keyCode == 32 && now - lastCallTime > 500) {
            shoot();
            lastCallTime = now;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Also depending on [target browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Date.now) you may want to use `new Date().getTime()` instead of `Date.now()`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's guaranteed that `keydown`/`keypress` events are always fired continuously. It may depend on the browser, operating system settings, etc. Even if they are, "fire rate" may fluctate. You probably don't want this.

I think a better idea would be to create a timer that's started when the first `keydown` event is fired, and stopped on `keyup` event.

http://jsfiddle.net/kPbLH/

```
var fireTimer = null;

function fire() {
    // do whatever you need
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && fireTimer === null) {
         fire(); // fire immediately...
         fireTimer = setInterval(fire, 500);  // ...and 500ms, 1000ms and so on after
    }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && fireTimer !== null) {
        clearInterval(fireTimer);
        fireTimer = null;
    }
});
```